# Samma ditthi vs Miccha ditthi

Tags: theravada

Can someone guide me? Whenever I try to concentrate on Samma Ditthi, some obstacle generate within this body? It's like mirage of something real! Its like a whirlpool of mass of atoms.  Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduent grasping for samma ditthi will result in renewed sankharas. What you describe seems like you are in fact intensifying sankharas. Samma will arise spontaneously, provided that you have stilled the sankharas (samatha-bhavana).

You could try renunciating your eagerness by following the tetrads of the anapanasati sutta step by step. As a suggestion, try to sustain the first tetrad until you have established samatha.

This enables further investigation (vipassana bhavana), which will gradually facilitate deepened samma ditthi.

https://suttacentral.net/mn118/en/bodhi

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are unwholesome mental formations you have accumulated in the past, coming to the surface.

If you give up bad kamma and maintain right view, the accumulated past formations will dissolve (after they reach a certain challenging intensity).

Samma ditthi is for the brave and not for the politically correct.

If you want to practice Buddhist meditation, your life must be relatively pure. Follow the five precepts. No porn, video games and other internet poisons.

Answer (score 1):

First of Samma Dhitti is not something you can just concentrate on, Samma Dhitti means

**Believe in Lord Buddha and the fourth noble truth, and it's the only way to attain Nirvana**

Michcha dhitti is the complete opposite way of it.

And what you trying to say is (if i'm getting it right), once you are trying to meditate, some irritating thoughts comes out of nowhere and break your concentration.

It is how our mind works, and it's completely normal, and there is no exact answer for that,
but there is a way to avoid such a thoughts,Anapanasathi and practice more.

Hope this would helps.

Comment: Also, You should consult a teacher who can guide you in your meditation journey.